# Change Slider Value with a Label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I created a Slider which displays it's value to a label as you can see below.
I want to add the option to change the slider value (position) with the label, so I made the label editable with `contenteditable="true"` - Now to change the value of the slider with my value in the label I thought of something like:

**Thought**:

```
    $('#cv_slider').on('input', function () {
        //function
    })
```

I can get the value in my console for the function: `console.log($(this).html())`
But all my tries to apply it to my slider failed, maybe it's because I started JS recently..

**HTML**:

```
<div class="range-slider">
    <input id="CV_SP1" class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="0.4" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.05">
    <label contenteditable="true" id="cv_slider" class="range-slider__value">0</label>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var rangeSlider = function() {
    var slider = $('.range-slider'),
        range = $('.range-slider__range'),
        value = $('.range-slider__value');

    slider.each(function() {

        value.each(function() {
            var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
            $(this).html(value * 100 + 'mm');
        });

        range.on('input', function() {
            $(this).next(value).html(this.value * 100 + 'mm');
        });
    });
};

rangeSlider();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try below snippet hope some modifications will fix this issue

```js
var rangeSlider = function() {
    var slider = $('.range-slider'),
    range = $('.range-slider__range'),
    value = $('.range-slider__value');

    slider.each(function() {

        value.each(function() {
            var value = $(this).prev().attr('value')* 100;
            $(this).html(value.toFixed(2));
        });

        range.on('input', function() {
            var val = this.value * 100;
            $(this).next(value).html(val.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
};

rangeSlider();
$('.range-slider__value').on('input', function (e) {
    var valSel = parseFloat($(this).text() / 100) || 0;
    $(this).prev().val(valSel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.min.css" integrity="sha512-Rp0yZ3NMh1xOUZ4VHYggmX4pq4ZJdpcOETH03qBD5qNDsqTBw1MzUnX0T5PcTJmr2mNTOmtbxsHaGwzjylNpHA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.css" integrity="sha512-FkNnPJevAkIHB3NqUiMadWNcoMcOCPQUMyF55JeAFZmPcSR6wK6TgZ0qL6bMrRqGNaaVS8CAwBYceORhdTUILQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.min.js" integrity="sha512-BUlWdwDeJo24GIubM+z40xcj/pjw7RuULBkxOTc+0L9BaGwZPwiwtbiSVzv31qR7TWx7bs6OPTE5IyfLOorboQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
    <input id="CV_SP1" class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="0.4" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.05">
    <label contenteditable="true" id="cv_slider" class="range-slider__value">0</label>mm
</div>
<div class="range-slider">
    <input id="CV_SP2" class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="0.4" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.05">
    <label contenteditable="true" id="cv_slider" class="range-slider__value">0</label>mm
</div>
<div class="range-slider">
    <input id="CV_SP3" class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="0.4" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.05">
    <label contenteditable="true" id="cv_slider" class="range-slider__value">0</label>mm
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you very much! Is it possible to do this with ID's ? Because when I have multiple sliders, it will change the value of all sliders.

Comment: Hey hi checkout updated code snippet. Now you can implement it multiple times.

Comment: Hey @maheshmthorat that works. Thanks! Do you know where in your JavaScript I need to implement .toFixed() ? Because sometimes with small values i will get something like: 3.5000000000000004 but I just want to display 3.5

Comment: Try this 
 $(this).prev().val(valSel.toFixed(2));})

Comment: Doesnt work :/.

Comment: Hello @TheCodingTentacle updated above code snippet with new code try once